# How to transform pyarrow Table in order to use it with pyarrow.compute methods

Tags: pyarrow

I have a pyarrow `Table`, which I create using `json.read_json()`. The table schema is the following:

```
pyarrow.Table
_id: string
user_id: string
local_date_str: timestamp[s]
datetime: timestamp[s]
data: struct<aggregatable_quantity: double>
  child 0, aggregatable_quantity: double
----
```

What I want to do is to sum up all the `aggregatable_quantity` values. To do this, I want to apply the `pyarrow.compute.sum` function, which takes an *array-like* argument. My first try was to produce an array-like object from the `data` column of the table I have, so I did the following:

```
table = json.read_json("my_table.json")
dat = table.column('data')
my_sum = pc.sum(dat)
```

because the `column()` function returns a `pyarrow.ChunkedArray` object, which **is** *array-like*. However, when I run the code, I got the following:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: Function 'sum' has no kernel matching input types (struct<aggregatable_quantity: double>)
```

So, I guess, although `dat` is array-like, at runtime it amounts to a `struct` and not an `array`, hence the exception. Then I looked into it some more and found the following work-around:

```
dat2 = dat.chunk(0)
datTable = pa.Table.from_struct_array(dat2)
pandArray = datTable.to_pandas()
datArray = pa.Array.from_pandas(pandArray.aggregatable_quantity)
my_sum = pc.sum(datArray)
```

This works and I get the sum I want. However, it feels like an overkill, having to convert to and from pandas in order to get to a `DoubleArray` object (the `datArray`). Is there a better way to do this and reach an array-like object that I can use with `pyarrow.compute` functions, starting from a `pyarrow.Table`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sum` doesn't supports *structs*, regardless of whether the array is chunked. The `struct_field` compute function can be used to extract the `aggregatable_quantity` field.

```py
pc.sum(pc.struct_field(table['data'], 'aggregatable_quantity'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Both your and @amoba 's answer work perfectly, so I set up a quick execution time test to come up with a criterion by which to choose what to accept. The `combine_chunks()` function gives, on average, a slightly better execution time than `struct_field()`, so I accepted that one, but they both work just fine. I upvoted both though!

Comment: Ok, let me apologise to @amoeba for this back-and-forth. It turns out that using `struct_field()` is what I went with in the end, because of the ability to specify the data field I want to use by name, e.g. `aggregatable_quantity`. Therefore, I am changing my vote. Really sorry, but I had to vote according to what I ended up using.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `combine_chunks()` to convert to a StructArray followed by `field()` to get the underlying Array before passing off to pc.sum. Something like this should work:

```py
table = json.read_json("my_table.json")
dat = table.column('data')
arr = dat.combine_chunks().field(0)
pc.sum(arr)
```

In case it helps, here's a reproducible example:

```py
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.compute as pc

tbl = pa.table({'a':pa.array([{'a': 1}, {'a': 2}, {'a': 3}], pa.struct(fields))})
col = tbl.column("a")
pc.sum(col.combine_chunks().field(0))
```

This produces `<pyarrow.Int64Scalar: 6>`.